# Click CSS Tab, Set php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have the following "pure CSS tab" code. What I want to do is load the PLAYER_CODE include file but do so with a variable set to a value when I click the tab. - When tab 1 is clicked, the $cat variable should be set to "music"
- When tab 2 is clicked, the $cat variable should be set to "radio"
- When tab 3 is clicked, the $cat variable should be set to "books"

This way the PLAYER_CODE include will pull up the correct media.

```
<div class="pc-tab">
        <input checked="checked" id="tab1" type="radio" name="pct" />
        <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="pct" />
        <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="pct" />
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li class="tab1">
                <label for="tab1">Music</label>
              </li>
              <li class="tab2">
                <label for="tab2">Radio</label>
              </li>
              <li class="tab3">
                <label for="tab3">Books</label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <section>
            <div class="tab1">Tab 01 <!-- $cat set to "music" -->
                <?php include 'player_code.php'; ?>
            </div>           

            <div class="tab2">Tab 02 <!-- $cat set to "radio" -->
                <?php include 'player_code.php'; ?>
            </div>

            <div class="tab3">Tab 03 <!-- $cat set to "books" -->
                <?php include 'player_code.php'; ?>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
```

Comment: Yes, but not as familiar - I will look now. Any resources you can suggest?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ or as part of jQuery http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ (jQuery is JavaScript library)

Comment: Just saw this on StckOvrFl "You can't able to change the php value using javascript. i.e Server scripts runs first after that client side script will take effect in that case you cant able to modify the same, since they already rendered in browsers" Maybe I need to do it with pure JS (variables)?

Comment: it depends on what you want

Answer (score 1):

Php processes on the backend. Based on the code posted it appears you want an interactive frontend functionality.

Either you edit to resubmit to the backend or use ajax to fetch the response and parse it within the section desired.

Below is using backend.

```
<?php
    // Init.
    $sFileName = '';
    $sName     = '';

    $aGet = $_GET;
    $sName = ( empty( $aGet[ 'type' ] ) ? '' : $aGet[ 'type' ] );
?>
<div class="pc-tab">
    <input checked="checked" id="tab1" type="radio" name="pct" />
    <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="pct" />
    <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="pct" />
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="tab1">
            <label for="tab1"><a href="?type=music">Music<a/></label>
            </li>
            <li class="tab2">
            <label for="tab2">><a href="?type=radio">Radio<a/></label>
            </li>
            <li class="tab3">
            <label for="tab3">><a href="?type=books">Books<a/></label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section>
        <div class="tab1"><?php echo $sName; ?>
            <?php 
            if( !empty( $sName ) )
            {
                require_once( $sName . '.php' );
            }
            ?>
        </div>           
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: I was looking for a front end solution (you are right) I am trying to avoid having the page reload.